# Three level navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create a three level drop down for global navigation in sharepoint. Most of the solutions that I came across showed changes in the master page (changing MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels) I did that but could not find a way to add third level for navigation under global navigation.
I want the navigation as Heading -> Heading 1 -> Link
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have enabled in every site (navigation settings) and subsite the option of "show pages" and "show sites".

Also, Please specify which build and which version of SharePoint you are using?

If you are using 2013 ,
Found the kb article (of August 2013 CU for SharePoint 2013) in which it is described that there was a bug fix around flyouts:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817616

Assume that you add a hierarchy of sub-sites to a SharePoint Server 2013 site on which the Publishing Infrastructure feature is enabled. In this situation, navigation hierarchies do not display more than two levels in the left nor top navigation controls.

Try adding "**StaticDisplayLevels="2"**" also alongwith setting MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels.

Comment: Hi @user2264989, I am using SharePoint designer 2010. I have checked the "show sites" checkbox but the "show pages" checkbox is disabled.I have created few pages and lists in an existing sharepoint site. I then added a tab to the top horizontal navigation and added links to the created pages. I now require a third level navigation to include links to pages. Is this possible?

Comment: Edited answer with another option to set static display levels

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But I am still unable to displaya third level navigation link. I have 3 links(say link1,link2,link3) under a tab heading. I want to have another 2 links under the link1. But I am unable to add a link under the link1. It just gets added to the heading. Please help me understand how do I go about this!